# Using a test-path within a copy-item in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, copy-item

I'm currently copying a file (from the variable `$_.'File Path'` which is set via a column in an SQL table) to another folder location (`$Path`).

The `$_.'File Path'` variable includes the folder location, file name, but not the extension. I'd like to set the extension via a test path, but I’m struggling to do so.

E.g. test if `$_.'File Path'` has an extension of *.PDF*, if this is true, copy.
If not, test if `$_.'File Path'` has an extension of *.doc*, if this is true, copy.
If not, test if `$_.'File Path'` has an extension of *.tif*……..

```
    Echo "Copying document and Prepending Document Date"
     $copy = [IO.FileInfo]$_.'File Path'
     $copy | Copy-Item -Destination "$path\$($_.'Date')_$($copy.Name)"
```

Comment: have you tried `Get-Item -Path $YourPath.*`? if your extension-less path is unique, then the wildcard will pick up the full file name.

Comment: Couldn't you do `$copy.Extension`? Then in an if statement: `if($copy.Extension -eq ".PDF") { #Copy Item}`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
$extensions = '.pdf', '.doc', '.tif' # add additional extensions as needed

# Create paths with prefix $_.'File-Path' with all the extensions.
# E.g., if $_.'File-Path' contains 'c:\path\to\document', this
# creates the following array:
#   'c:\path\to\document.pdf', 'c:\path\to\document.doc', 'c:\path\to\document.tif'
$filePathsToTest = $extensions -replace '^', [regex]::Escape($_.'File-Path')

# ...

# See if any of the constructed file paths exist.
if ($existingFiles = Get-Item -ErrorAction Ignore $filePathsToTest) { 
  Copy-Item -LiteralPath $existingFiles `
            -Destination "$path\$($_.'Date')_$(Split-Path -Leaf $_.'File-Path')"
}
```

Comment: This creates the folders as before, but doesn't copy the file across.

Comment: @LFuller: I'm not sure what you're saying in the comment, but I've re-read the question and have substantially revised the answer - please have another look.